# Randomizing minute for crontab entries between servers

Tags: linux, cron, puppet

I have a common [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/) recipe for a set of our servers. One of the puppet-managed files is `/etc/crontab` that contains the original `cron.daily`, `cron.weekly` and `cron.monthly` entries.

The problem of the common `/etc/crontab` file here is that all cronjobs are run at the exactly same time in all of our servers. For example, daily backups consumed all our backup server resources as all servers are feeding it at same time.

What is the preferred way to randomize the exact minute of the daily/weekly/monthly runs between servers, while still keeping the puppet recipe common between all servers?

I have been thinking a few different options:

- Running `sleep` & `$RANDOM` before the actual job. In this way, the `crontab` would be similar in every host but the exact time of running the daily/weekly jobs would vary. There would be variation even inside the same server (for example daily run interval could vary between 23-25 hours).
- Calculating an integer value from the hostname and running all jobs with `at` + "the hostname-based integer" minutes. A bit hacky, but might work...
- Some other method, but what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puppet has an [`fqdn_rand`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#fqdnrand) function that you can use for this:

```
minute => fqdn_rand(60)
```

Comment: Simple as that! I had completely missed this function. Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of randomizing cronjobs, you should randomize your scripts to `sleep`.

I usually do this kind of thing with:

`sleep $((RANDOM%120)) && /bin/sh -c /path/to/my/cronjob`

In this way all cronjobs can start at the same time, but they will randomically sleep between `0 and 120`.

Comment: I don't like this solution, because just looking at cron logs you have no way to know how much time has been spent sleeping and how much executing the script, you need additional logging from your script and/or the processes you are executing.

Comment: cron logs don't log the time of execution? i doubt that. you can always use logger -p info to log everything using the already available syslog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get "random" integer by hashing FQDN. In erb-template:

```
<%= Time.at( fqdn.hash % 10000 ).strftime('%M')  %> * * * * myuser /bin/mycommand
```

But puppet can do it more gracefully. In manifest:

```
$minute = inline_template("<%= Time.at( fqdn.hash % 10000 ).strftime('%M')  %>")
cron { my-cron:
    minute => $minute,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lot of different kind of implementation examples :
http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Cron_Patterns